# How to get value from combobox into next url

Tags: php, mysql, combobox, fpdf

I wonder if anyone can help my problem, in which way I can get value from combobox selection into next url by clicking so I can make it as a parameter to the pdf report. 
this is my code to add some combobox :

```
<form method="GET">

        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Bulan</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <select name="bln" class="form-control">
                <option value="1">Januari</option>
                <option value="2">Februari</option>
                <option value="3">Maret</option>
                <option value="4">April</option>
                <option value="5">Mei</option>
                <option value="6">Juni</option>
                <option value="7">Juli</option>
                <option value="8">Agustus</option>
                <option value="9">September</option>
                <option value="10">Oktober</option>
                <option value="11">November</option>
                <option value="12">Desember</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Tahun</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <select name="thn" class="form-control">
                <option value="2018">2018</option>
                <option value="2019">2019</option>
                <option value="2020">2020</option>
                <option value="2021">2021</option>
                <option value="2022">2022</option>
                <option value="2023">2023</option>
                <option value="2024">2024</option>
                <option value="2025">2025</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        </form>

        <?php
        if (isset($_GET['bln'])) {
        $bln = $_GET['bln'];
        $thn = $_GET['thn'];
        }

        ?>

        <a class="btn btn-success" href="rep-cuti-tahunan-all.php?bln="$bln"&thn="$thn"">Print</a>
```

so I would like to put `$bln` and `$thn` into `<a class="btn btn-success" href="rep-cuti-tahunan-all.php?bln="$bln"&thn="$thn"">Print</a>`
and get my report in pdf exactly according to that parameters

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to add it as a parameter.Just change your form like this.

```
<form method="GET" action ="rep-cuti-tahunan-all.php">
       ....
</form>
```

then on your php file, you fetch the selected value.

```
<?php
....
    if (isset($_GET['bln'])) {
            $bln = $_GET['bln'];
            $thn = $_GET['thn'];
                }
    ....

//Do your print method ...
    ?>
```